# React test fails with IndexSizeError when setting rows on a textarea in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I'm trying to implement a test in React testing library to verify that the "Add new row" functionality in my table works.

I verify the amount of rows initally, then I click the button, then i want to check the amount of rows after.

Here is the test:

```
describe('Table Buttonbar', () => {
  it('Add new problem creates 3 new rows', async () => {
    const allVisibleRowsLength = allRows.filter(
      (row) => row.status !== PlanElementStatus.COMPLETED
    ).length;

    const plan = customRender(
      <Plan planId={mocks.planId} />,
      mocks.response
    );

    const buttonBar = await plan.findByRole('toolbar');
    const addProblemButton = await within(buttonBar).findByText('Problem');

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(
        plan.getAllByTestId((el) => rowTypes.includes(el))
      ).toHaveLength(allVisibleRowsLength);
    });

    act(() => {
      userEvent.click(addProblemButton); //Fails here
    });

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(
        plan.getAllByTestId((el) => rowTypes.includes(el))
      ).toHaveLength(allVisibleRowsLength + 3);
    });
  });
```

The errormessage I get is this(with lots of node_modules stacktrace i removed):

```
console.error
    Error: Uncaught [IndexSizeError: The index is not in the allowed range.]

 console.error
    The above error occurred in the <TextArea> component
```

What happens is that when the button is clicked, 3 new rows(1 main row and 2 subrows) are added to the table in "edit-mode" meaning instead of showing values, it shows inputfields, including a textarea.

This textarea is rendered from a custom component  which is made to make the textarea resize dynamically when typing.

I have found that the guilty code in the component is this:

```
//Sets the height of the textarea on mount so you dont have to type in it for it to resize(in case it already has a value)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (textAreaRef.current) {
      const currentRows = Math.ceil(
        textAreaRef.current.scrollHeight / fontSize - 1
      );

      textAreaRef.current.rows = minMax(currentRows, minRows, maxRows); // This is what triggers the error I believe
    }
  }, [minRows, maxRows]);
```

I have identified the code that produces the error by simply adding console.logs everywhere. Last print is right before `textAreaRef.current.rows = minMax(currentRows, minRows, maxRows)`

minMax function looks like this:

```
const minMax = (num: number, min: number, max: number): number =>
  Math.min(Math.max(num, min), max);
```

Problem is, I have no clue why it happens or what I can do about it. It works perfectly fine when I run the app normally. The value it tries to set rows equal to here is `1`, so it "should" be fine?

Anyone have any idea of what I can do here?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the minMax function uses an array? If you believe the behavior is right you could use a try catch around it, but it is throwing an error

Comment: updated question to show minMax function. No it doesnt use array. I just tried wrapping it in try-catch and it didn't throw an error. Or i couldn't find the console.error print in the terminal after i ran the test.

Comment: I think the error is because fontSize = NaN. I calculate fontSize outside the component like this: `const fontSize = parseInt(
  getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--font-size')
    .replace('px', ''),
  10
);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I calculated `fontSize` outside my Component like this:

```
const fontSize = parseInt(
  getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--font-size')
    .replace('px', ''),
  10
);

const TextArea: React.FC<TextAreaProps> = ({
  minRows = 1,
  maxRows = 10,
  defaultValue,
  onChange,
}) => {
...
```

In tests, that returned NaN which created this error. Probably from `Math.Ceil`

Solution was to just add a fallback value for tests like so:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (textAreaRef.current) {
      const currentRows = Math.ceil(
        textAreaRef.current.scrollHeight / (fontSize || 12) - 1 // fontSize fallback to make tests happy(calculated to NaN in tests)
      );
      textAreaRef.current.rows = minMax(currentRows, minRows, maxRows);
    }
  }, [minRows, maxRows]);
```